# Get Newly generated ID (i.e. scopeIdentity) in Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am added a record in my table e.g. `Orders`. After adding the record i want to get the newly generated ID of the inserted record. Like `SCOPEIDENTY` in SQL.

But how can i do this in Entity Framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you saved your changes, your entity object should reflect the newly generated ID automagically. It's one of the many great things about the Entity Framework. :-)

Comment: Thanks I got it. I was thinking on wrong side :-)
Ya its a good think. :-)